# Use JDBC to connect to Hive in Jruby generates ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jdbc, hive, jruby

I am trying to connect to hive using JRuby, this is part of my code

```
require 'java'

module JavaLang
   include_package 'java.lang'
end

module JavaSql
   include_package 'java.sql'
end

JavaLang::Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").newInstance

..rest of the code
```

I get a ClassNotFoundException when calling Class.forName

I tried to add the hive-jdbc.jar to the classpath using the following command:

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/my/home/dir/bin/*

The bin directory that I created contains the hive-jdbc jar but I am still getting this error.

How can I add the jar to my classpath so that it is recognizable by Class.forName?

P.S. I was using the code [here](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2007/05/05/connect-jruby-to-mysql-using-jdbc/) as a guide to create my code as I am new to JRuby

Answer (score 0):

That was resolved by adding an import statement:

```
import 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver'
```

and removing the Class.forName call:

```
JavaLang::Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").newInstance
```